# Is it possible to apply script and link for only some particular div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply this link and script in my html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

On my Html page i have one form and div. My `div` is coming as  per requirment but when form is not comming correct. I have some different set of stylesheet and script for `form`.

Is there any way to by which we can apply this script for link not for div. OR do I need to write seperate class and script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts and Style sheets once loaded are available for the complete HTML document and any style defined in these will be applied to the elements referencing them.

You will have to design your style sheets in a way so that they apply on to a form element or a div.

Comment: Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

No. Stylesheets and JavaScript apply to the whole document unless the script or stylesheet itself limits what it effects.

Answer (score -1):

```
https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/
The :scope CSS pseudo-class matches the elements that are a reference point for selectors to match against. In HTML, a new reference point can be defined using the scoped attribute of the <style>. If no such attribute is used on an HTML page, the reference point is the <html> element.
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=scope — Scoped CSS has been removed from the spec and isn't supported anywhere outside of Firefox. You also need to read the formatting instructions for answers, and quote the relevent part of the material you link to (the `:scope` psuedo-class isn't helpful, the `script` attribute would have been if it hadn't been abandoned)